# Why do Omkara and Kichalu (Kathor) not try to kill each other after Captan's death?

Tags: plot-explanation, omkara

In the opening fight scene of *Omkara*, which takes place in the bricks kiln, Kichalu accidently kills Captan, but he does not try to kill Omkara neither does Omkara try to kill him. Why? Kichalu is shown under shock, but Omkara is shown pretty sure that after the death of Captan Kichalu will not pull the trigger any more.